# Convert Categorical Data into binary (1&0) in R Studio

Tags: r

I have a dataset comparing cases to categories of mental illness. In the data set, it is reported as 0 for no mental illness, 1 for mood disorders, 2 for behavioral disorders, 3 for other, and 4 for disorder like symptoms. I am trying to convert my dataset (mentallIllness) so that if you show any symptoms or have any disorder (I.e. you have a 1 to 4) it counts as a 1 (just yes that you have signs/have disorder) or 0 for no mental illness.

How can I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: `my_data <- 0:4; my_data2 <- 1*(my_data>0)`

Comment: @JonSpring, please post as an answer? (To the OP: welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a pretty basic question, which would be better received if you indicated what you've tried so far to solve the problem yourself ... `ifelse(my_data == 0, 0, 1)` would be another choice ...)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a vector with numbers from 0 to 4:

```
my_data <- c(0:4, 2, 3, 0)
my_data
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 2 3 0
```

Here are a few ways to convert all the non-zeros to 1:

```
1*(my_data>0)
#[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
as.numeric(my_data>0)
#[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

In both of these cases, the term `(my_data>0)` tests each value in `my_data` to evaluate if it is greater than 0, if so the result is TRUE, otherwise FALSE. We can multiply TRUE/FALSE by 1, or convert to numeric, to change those to 1/0.

As Ben Bolker suggested, we could use `ifelse` to get the same results:

```
ifelse(my_data == 0, 0, 1)
#[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

---

Your vector might live in a data frame, like:

```
my_df <- data.frame(my_data = c(0:4, 2, 3, 0))
```

We could use the same code to make a new variable, or overwrite the existing one:

```
my_df$recoded = ifelse(my_df$my_data == 0, 0, 1)
my_df

#  my_data recoded
#1       0       0
#2       1       1
#3       2       1
#4       3       1
#5       4       1
#6       2       1
#7       3       1
#8       0       0
```